# How can I translate the name of my Rails app using i18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n

I'm using Rails version 5.1.2. I am interested in changing the name of my application, for display on the site, and in the title. The actual title of the website is multiple words, while the name of the app is only part of that phrase. I know how to change the name of the app itself, but I'm not interested in doing that. I just want it to be displayed as this translated form wherever I may place it. I couldn't figure out how to do this within the `en.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

In your **en.yml** you can write something like this,

```
en:
  info:
    title: "What u want"
```

And In your view just call it like below,

```
%h1= t('info.title')
```

Hope it will help